# Remove parentheses in a List

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I want the output to be:    a,b   when the input is {a,b} . How do I do this please? Flatten command does not work.

Comment: You could use something like `removeBraces[list_] := Row[Riffle[list, ","]]`

Comment: Do you want a string that is "a,b", or the values of a,b, or just the symbols? Are you doing anything with it afterward, for instance `f[Sequence@@{a,b}]` will give `f[a,b]`.

Comment: @Jason B. thanks so much. This works like a dream...

Comment: Or `f @@ {a, b}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to display the list, then you can use Row to format it however you like:

```
removeBraces[list_] := Row[Riffle[list, ","]]
```